# Actualizar BD en firebase con múltiples datos?

Tags: python-3.x, json, firebase

Estoy trabado de de agregar datos en Firebase para un players en específico pero me genera este error

```
put() got multiple values for argument 'connection'
```

Y no entiendo cómo agregarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la función que utilizo para actualizar el players.

```
def Newcompra(user,items):
    global PlayerDB,TiendaDB
    
    info = {
        "id": TiendaDB[items]["id"],
        "nombre": TiendaDB[items]["nombre"],
        "historia": TiendaDB[items]["historia"]
        
    }
    Fire.put_async("/players/",user,"/bolso_info/",items,"/",info)
    
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
Fire.put_async("/players/",user,"/bolso_info/",items,"/",info).
```

Modificar el método para `PUT` solo y quite una barra invertida y quedó de esta manera.

```py
Fire.put("/players/",user,"/bolso_info",items,info)
```

Y agregó el objeto de manera correcta de esta manera  solo hay tres parámetros.